# Implementing Filtering (Text and Combobox) in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I am trying to put up some code that will allow a DataGrid to be filtered by a TextBox or ComboBox. I have already put up filtering code for the TextBox and now for the Combobox type filter, I am not very sure about the approach.

Firstly, I have inherited DataGrid and all my filtering code is placed there. For placing the Filter on the datagrid I have choosen the DataGrid's header. I wan't to control what type of filter to show using attached properties defined in the inherited DataGrid Class. Here is one of them that identifies the filter type to use (textbox or combobox).

```
    public class FilteringDataGrid : DataGrid {
        ....
        //Dependency Properties for Combobox or Text search.
        public static DependencyProperty FilterTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FilterType",
                 typeof(FilterTypeEnum), typeof(DataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(FilterTypeEnum.TextBoxOnly));
```

It is set at DataGridColumn level.

In the DataGrid ColumnHeaderTemplate, I am trying to read the above attached property. However I dont know how to access the property set at Column level, in ColumnHeaderTemplate. I will use this property value in Trigger to present either TextBox or Combobox as filter. **How do I access the value of this property in ColumnHeaderTemplate (or Template Triggers to be precise)**.

Here is relevant part of DataGrid ColumnHeaderTemplate

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:fg="clr-namespace:ThemingControls.CustomControls"> <!--Inherited DataGrid Control namespace -->

                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Grid>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> 
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                                            ....
                                            <Path x:Name="SortArrow"
                                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                                            ....
     <!-- Combobox or TextBox show either one based on Column FilterType attached Property  -->
                                            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  IsEditable="False" 
                                                      />
                                            <fg:DelayTextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                            ....

<!-- Triggers to show TextBox/Combobox based on attached property of column -->

                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="fg:FilteringDataGrid.FilterType" Value="NonEditableComboBox">
                                        <Setter Property="fg:DelayTextBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The above code runs but I get Combobox type filters in all column even though some columns have TextBox set as the attached property (FilterType). This means that the trigger above is not working. Any ideas how to access the attached property set in datagrid Column. ie. access it in the ColumnHeaderTemplate to be more precise.

Comment: I don't think you are referring to the value correctly if it is an enumeration.  Try FilterTypeEnum.NonEditableComboBox

Comment: Actually, I had tried that before but the wpf complains that "FilterTypeEnum.NonEditableComboBox is not a valid value for FilterTypeEnum". I also tried using fg:FilterTypeEnum.NonEditableComboBox and it results in the same "invalid value"

Comment: Not sure how to put a converter in trigger or even sure if it can be done but that is what I would try.  You can see what is coming in and even catch and exception.

Comment: @Blam, Its late night here now, so I will follow your suggestion tommorrow. Thanks for looking at the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would let DataGrid do it's thing - display the data it is given; Instead Filter /  Sort / Group the collection that is bound to the datagrid's Itemsource, there is a ton of samples including MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#filtering